# How do I run descriptive statistics in R for each file in a directory and append it to a data frame (txt file final output as a table)?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, file, append

I have a folder of files (csv) that have filtered/gated data -- two columns (dihedral angle vs bend angle). It was filtered based upon an individualized min and max for each file.

I need to be able to get at least the mean, median, sd, skewness, and kurtosis for each column of each file and have that data presented as a table. (One line per file in the final product)

I am not familiar with what R packages that maybe suitable for this task, so I was trying to do something simple. I can get it to work for a single file, but I have over 200 files. They will likely be updating, so I'll have to run this multiple times.

```
module load ccs/container/R/4.1.0
R

library(moments)

files <- list.files("/mnt/gpfs2_4m/scratch/username/fs_scripts/foldedstart_*", pattern="*.csv", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

cat("filename","\t","dihedral mean","\t","bend mean","\t","dihedral median","\t","bend median","\t","dh sd","\t","bd sd","\t","dh skew","\t","bd skew","\t","dh kurt","\t","bd kurt","\n")

for (currentFile in files) {
  df <- read.table(fileName[i], header=TRUE)

  z1 <- mean(df$V1)
  z2 <- median(df$V1)
  z3 <- sd(df$V1)
  z4 <- skewness(df$V1)
  z5 <- kurtosis(df$V1)

  z7 <- mean(df$V2)
  z8 <- median(df$V2)
  z9 <- sd(df$V2)
  z10 <- skewness(df$V2)
  z11 <- kurtosis(df$V2)
  
  cat(filename,"\t",z1,"\t",z7,"\t",z2,"\t",z8,"\t",z3,"\t",z9,"\t",z4,"\t",z10,"\t",z5,"\t",z11,"\n")

  write.table(newdata, file=statsFileName[i]))
}
```

The "first cat line" is the header and labels.

The "for cat line" likely goes "no where," but it is the format that I am trying to achieve.

The "write.table line" is something that I found, but I don't think it may be appropriate for this.

I truly appreciate any help on this. I am not that familiar with R and the examples that I have found do not appear to relate enough to what I trying to do for me to adapt them.

**Edit**: This is a plot from where the data is visualized. I’m looking for the medians (centers) of each major area of density. Trying to give some context.

Example of what the data looks like (head and tail) and some of the files in the folder

Added screenshot for Rui

Added screenshots for Rowan

[image: Plot example]
[image: Data example]
[image: Output for Rui - nothing printed, but I did try it for an individual file]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't you prefer to write the stats to a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

The following computes all statistics the question asks for for each file and writes a table of results to a CSV file.

```
library(moments)

stats <- function(filename, na.rm = TRUE) {
  tryCatch({
    x <- read.csv(filename)
    xbar <- colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    med <- apply(x, 2, median, na.rm = na.rm)
    S <- apply(x, 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm)
    skwn <- skewness(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    kurt <- kurtosis(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    #
    # return a data.frame, it will 
    # make the code simpler further on
    out <- data.frame(
      filename = filename, 
      dihedral.mean = xbar[1],
      bend.mean = xbar[2],
      dihedral.median = med[1],
      bend.median = med[2],
      dihedral.sd = S[1],
      bend.sd = S[2],
      dihedral.skewness = skwn[1],
      bend.skewness = skwn[2],
      dihedral.kurtosis = kurt[1],
      bend.kurtosis = kurt[2]
    )
    row.names(out) <- NULL
    out
  },
  error = function(e) e
  )
}

statsFileName <- "statsfile.txt"

#files <- list.files("/mnt/gpfs2_4m/scratch/username/fs_scripts/foldedstart_*", pattern="*.csv", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
files <- list.files("~/Temp", "^t.*\\.csv$")

newdata <- lapply(files, stats)
ok <- !sapply(newdata, inherits, "error")
cat("files read:", sum(ok), "\n")
if(any(!ok)) {
  cat("errors:", sum(!ok), "\n")
  err_list <- list(
    files = files[!ok],
    error = conditionMessage(newdata[!ok])
  )
}

newdata <- do.call(rbind, newdata[ok])
write.csv(newdata, file = statsFileName, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The statsfile.txt is returning empty. I did change ~/Temp to the directory containing the data and then ran R from that directory.

Comment: It really doesn’t matter whether it is comma or tab delimited. That’s an easy one to modify as needed. I will need to eventually be able to look at the table and compare values while looking my plots.

Comment: @Josh Yes, I tested on my computer, so I used a `~/Temp` directory. The path posted in the question is commented out. Have you tried it with that path, with your `files` vector?

Comment: I have, but the file returns empty. (Actually a pair of quotes “” and was 3kb.) No errors pop-up. I tried a couple variations, but couldn’t get it to work. I’ll try again tomorrow. I understand this enough to see that it will do what I need and what it should be doing.

Comment: @Josh Can you put a `print(dim(x))` statement right after `read.csv` and post the output in a comment? (Or `print(class(x))` or both.)

Comment: I added those statements and nothing printed out. I went ahead and tried it for an individual file, so you can see what that says. I also added two pics, one showing head and tail of an individual file and the other is the code I entered into R for both your script and the individual file. I did check the folder and nothing went there either. The statsfile.txt only has a pair of quotes in it - ""

Comment: @Josh In `list.files`, you are using *my* pattern (I tested the code with a file whose name starts with `t`), try `pattern="\\.csv"` instead. Nothing printed out because the `files` vector was probably empty. Get completely rid of my `list.files` instruction and use your original one.

Comment: I missed that one. I restarted from the original script. I ran it again, "^mode*.*\\.csv$" , and it recognized the files, but had issues after that. I attached a screenshot.

Comment: @Josh Apparently you have errors reading the files, I have changed the code to trap errors and only rbind and write the files that were read without errors. The list `err_list` is only created if there were errors, it has the filename and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses dplyr to summarise each file, combines the summaries into a single dataframe, then writes the results to a csv file.

```
library(moments)
library(dplyr)

csv_output_path <- "./results.csv"
data_dir <- "./data"

### Create dummy csv files for reproducibility ###
if(!dir.exists(data_dir)) dir.create(data_dir)
for(i in 1:200){
    write.csv(data.frame(V1 = runif(100), V2 = runif(100)),
              file = paste0(data_dir, "/file_", i, ".csv"),
              row.names = FALSE)
}

### Summarise files ###
files <- list.files(data_dir, pattern = ".csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

all_results <- vector("list", length(files)) # results placeholder

# Loop that calculates summary statistics
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    currentFile <- files[i]
    df <- tryCatch(read.csv(file = currentFile, header=TRUE), 
                   error = function(e) NULL)
    if(is.null(df))
        next
    result <- df %>% summarise_all(list(mean = mean, median = median, 
                                        sd = sd, skew = skewness, kur = kurtosis))%>% 
        mutate(file = currentFile) %>% # add filename to the result
        select(file, everything()) # reorder 
    all_results[[i]] <- result
}

# Combine results into a single df
final_table <- bind_rows(all_results)

# write file
write.csv(final_table, csv_output_path, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it, however, an error is coming up. 

I changed ./data to the directory of the files and ran R from that directory

Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

It does create an empty file named results.csv

Comment: I don't know if this could be a problem, but I get this warning when loading dplyr:    > library(dplyr)

Attaching package: 'dplyr'

The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Comment: Should “list” (at vector(“list”,) be replaced with something like a filename or is it a list variable from the line above it, list.files?

Comment: Hi Josh, the error was because list.files() did not find the "./data/" directory in your filesystem. If you use the full directory to your data files, like in your original code chunk, it should solve the problem. I have added some variables at the top of my answer that explicitly sets the input data directory, and output path of the csv file.

Comment: The warning about dplyr masking objects just means that when you call the filter() function it will use the version of the function from the dplyr package rather than filter from the stats package - so not a problem in this case.

The line with vector("list") is creating an empty placeholder list with n_file elements. The  list will get populated with summary statistics for each file after every iteration of the for loop. The list is coverted into a more friendly data.frame at the end of the script with bind_rows

Comment: I've gotten both solutions presented here to work up unto the same point, interestingly. I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: I got this one to work! However, that error message is still present "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input" and I'm curious as to what it means.

Comment: Hi Josh, one of the files found by list.files() seems to causes an error for you when input to read.csv(). It is hard to say what the cause is without further information, but as Rui Barradas suggests, skipping any file that causes an error might work. I implement this with tryCatch. Changing the search pattern to ".csv$" might also be more robust in case any non-csv files have ".csv" in the middle of the filename somehow.